# It seems that the lecturer is making a grammatical mistake

Tags: word-usage, expressions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=88)

> you can think of machine learning, deep learning in
>   general as modeling a function   that takes an input that can be an
>   image, a speech, a natural language or a CSV file, give it to a box and
>   get an output that can be classification

in this context, there are 3 steps in which the function do its job

```
1. takes an input
2. gives it to a box
3. gets an output
```

so, the "give" and "get" are not grammatical, am I right about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lecturer has a very thick French accent and is clearly not a native English speaker, so I think it is understandable that he made some errors. You are correct that *give* and *get* should be *gives* and *gets*, because the subject is a singular function. “a speech” and “a natural language” and “can be classification” also sound slightly off. (“a fragment of speech/natural language” and “is a classification” are probably what the “correct” versions would be).